# Ability to determine project wide if any variables are not used in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a bunch of variables floating around my Terraform project. To clean things up, I'd like to remove any that aren't being used. Is there an easy way with Terraform to discern which variables aren't being used by the application?

Comment: Probably not an "easy way" but you could iteratively remove their declarations and execute `validate` to observe the effects.

Comment: Take a look at this [python script](https://alexwlchan.net/2019/05/finding-unused-variables-in-a-terraform-module/#putting-it-all-together).   I have not tested it.  It uses an unofficial  [python module to parse hcl](https://pypi.org/project/pyhcl/) (up to 0.12).   As far as I can tell, it does not handle locals.

Comment: If using intellij, with the terraform plugin installed: A variable that is used, upon deleted, will give you IDE errors. You can try deleting one by one and seeing if any red appears.